mypy warning on numpy.apply_along_axis
Edit Oct-18-2024:
An even more trivial reproduction of the problem is shown below.

mypy_arg_type.py:

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import random

def winner(_: NDArray[np.bytes_]) -> bytes | None:
    return b"." if bool(random.randint(0, 1)) else None

board = np.full((2, 2), ".", "|S1")
for w in np.apply_along_axis(winner, 0, board):
    print(w)


>> python mypy_arg_type.py

b'.'
None


>> mypy mypy_arg_type.py

mypy_arg_type.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "apply_along_axis" has incompatible type "Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[bytes_]]], bytes | None]"; expected "Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]], _SupportsArray[dtype[Never]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Never]]]]"  [arg-type]
mypy_arg_type.py:9: note: This is likely because "winner" has named arguments: "_". Consider marking them positional-only
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)


Original question:
I'm working on a problem to determine the winner of a Connect Four game, given the position of the pieces on the board.
The board is of size 6x7, and each column is marked with a letter from A to G. The winner, if any, will have 4 pieces of identical color in a row, column, diagonal or anti-diagonal.
Example:
Input: ["A_Red", "B_Yellow", "A_Red", "B_Yellow", "A_Red", "B_Yellow", "G_Red", "B_Yellow"]
Board:
R Y . . . . R
R Y . . . . .
R Y . . . . .
. Y . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .

Winner: Yellow
The following code determines a winner.
import itertools
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def who_is_winner(pieces: list[str]) -> str:
    def parse_board() -> NDArray[np.bytes_]:
        m, n = 6, 7
        indices = [0] * n
        # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.strings.html#fixed-width-data-types
        # One-byte encoding, the byteorder is ‘|’ (not applicable)
        board = np.full((m, n), ".", "|S1")
        for p in pieces:
            col = ord(p[0]) - ord("A")
            board[indices[col], col] = p[2]
            indices[col] += 1

        return board

    def winner(arr: NDArray[np.bytes_]) -> np.bytes_ | None:
        i = len(arr)
        xs = next(
            (xs for j in range(i - 3) if (xs := set(arr[j : j + 4])) < {b"R", b"Y"}),
            {None},
        )
        return xs.pop()

    def axis(x: int) -> np.bytes_ | None:
        # https://numpy.org/doc/2.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis
        # Axis 0 is column-wise, 1 is row-wise.
        return next(
            (w for w in np.apply_along_axis(winner, x, board) if w is not None), None
        )

    def diag(d: int) -> np.bytes_ | None:
        # https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html#numpy-diagonal
        # Diagonal number is w.r.t. the main diagonal.
        b = board if bool(d) else np.fliplr(board)
        return next(
            (w for d in range(-3, 4) if (w := winner(b.diagonal(d))) is not None), None
        )

    board = parse_board()
    match next(
        (
            w
            for f, i in itertools.product((axis, diag), (0, 1))
            if (w := f(i)) is not None
        ),
        None,
    ):
        case b"Y":
            return "Yellow"
        case b"R":
            return "Red"
        case _:
            return "Draw"

However, this generates a mypy violation as follows:
error: Argument 1 to "apply_along_axis" has incompatible type "Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[bytes_]]], bytes_ | None]"; expected "Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]], _SupportsArray[dtype[bytes_]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[bytes_]]]]"  [arg-type]
note: This is likely because "winner" has named arguments: "arr". Consider marking them positional-only

According to the documentation of apply_along_axis, it is supposed to return a single value, which is consistent with the code above.
How to fix this violation? Making function winner positional-only makes no difference, except that suggestion is gone.
I'm using Python 3.12.5 with mypy 1.11.2.

Does it run?  Is the problem just with the mypy typing?  Why are you using this apply... in the first place?  Instead, for example a simple iteration.  apply... is not a speed tool; it just makes iteration over the axes of 3d+ array prettier.   If arr is a 2d array it doesn't help.  Without testing, the action within winner doesn't look very array-like.  It looks list/tuple like.  What exactly does it return?

I think the problem is with what winner returns. You say it returns None.  Normally it would return a scalar or array. The docs show -> (Nj...).  Apply... is used to apply some function to 1d slices of an array, returning the result as a new array.  It performs a test calc to determine the exact shape of the return array.

@hpaulj winner is declared to return Optional[np.bytes_]. However, see edit.

Your simplified example can return different dtypes - 'S1' or object depending on whether the first random returns a byte or None.   Do you get the same mypy error if you replace the apply with np.array([winner(i) for i in board) (or board.T)?

By studying the overloaded signatures of apply_along_axis, I came to the conclusion that it is not defined to return None, causing the mypy violation. There's no real reason to not return None though, and I've opened a mypy ticket about it. We will see whether it gets kicked to numpy.
Overload 1:
def [_P`-1, _SCT: generic] apply_along_axis(func1d: Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]], **_P], _SupportsArray[dtype[_SCT]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[_SCT]]]], axis: SupportsIndex, arr: Buffer | _SupportsArray[dtype[Any]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]] | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | _NestedSequence[bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes], *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> ndarray[Any, dtype[_SCT]]

Overload 2:
def [_P`-1] apply_along_axis(func1d: Callable[[ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]], **_P], Buffer | _SupportsArray[dtype[Any]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]] | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | _NestedSequence[bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes]], axis: SupportsIndex, arr: Buffer | _SupportsArray[dtype[Any]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]] | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | _NestedSequence[bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes], *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]

I modified the function winner to return a null byte string (b"") instead of None, and replaced all return types of np.bytes_ to bytes. That fixed the problem.
